# How does Content Security Policy actually prevent an attack?

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

From my understanding, the Content Security Policy header (or meta tag in the page head) specifies which elements are allowed to be loaded in a web page.

This means that, if an attacker is able to modify the content of the page, and adds a call to a harmful javascript script, the script won't be loaded, because it comes from a domain not specifically allowed by the CSP.

Is this correct?

If so, what prevents the attacker from modifying the CSP header itself, thus enabling calls to his script?

Comment: If the attacker can modify the content of the page, then they've already won. The idea of CSP is to keep a malicious script (or other resource) from executing in the first place. If a *trusted* script messes with the CSP, then that trusted script is the problem (and shouldn't have been trusted).

Comment: @CertainPerformance This isn't really true. The CSP header cannot be altered by JavaScript, and it wins out over the meta tag that could be "messed with". The whole point of CSP is that, if an attacker *does* modify the content of a page, all is not lost. That's really the express purpose of it, to prevent the modifications an attacker does from doing harm.

Comment: @meagar Ah, so all Javascript can do is modify the HTML tag, but not the actual initial header, and the browser only cares about the initial header?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The browser will respect whichever one is more restrictive. So a malicious script can add a more lenient `<meta>` tag, but it will be ignored if the header is more restrictive. Effectively, the meta tag can only *tighten* whatever the header specified, not loosen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many scenarios where an attacker can modify a page, but not headers.

For example, an XSS attack that injects script into the page will be able to inject additional script, but cannot modify headers sent along with the initial page. CSP could prevent the injected script from running, and could also prevent it from loading any additional script.

CSP is an example of [defence in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)). Just because it fails when an attacker has completely taken over the server hosting a page doesn't mean it has no value.

Comment: @Kaiido see https://writingexplained.org/defence-vs-defense-difference and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252503/are-british-international-english-terms-acceptable-e-g-brackets-instead-of

Comment: My apologies, as a French speaker, *defence*  is a common typo for the one and only "défense"

Comment: @Kaiido No problem, as a Canadian on the Internet I'm used to my spelling being viewed as wrong :)

Comment: This makes sense, I was thinking of a MITM attack that would allow them to change the header, but did not think of another attack done later after the page is loaded

Comment: @NDUF Yes, CSP is one part of the larger solution. CSP cannot protect against MITM attacks where the attacker can modify headers or intercept entire requests. That's the job of SSL for the initial connection, and [subresource integrity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity) for included scripts. In the case where an attacker has actually compromised the server, it's too late for any downstream security like CSP to help.